# Chart JS tooltip and label width is zeroed

Tags: javascript, python, flask, html5-canvas, chart.js

tooltips and labels width seems to be 0 on localhost with same code as example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKhyr.png

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, this is the code:
https://pastebin.com/mt9WCdhe

```
        var MONTHS = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
        var config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: MONTHS,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'My First dataset',
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    data: randomData(),
                    fill: false,
                }, {
                    label: 'My Second dataset',
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    data: randomData(),
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: false,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Test graph'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false,
                },
                hover: {
                    mode: 'nearest',
                    intersect: false
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Month'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Value'
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        };

        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
        };
```

Example used:
https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html

No error on console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems on Brave Browser there´s a glitch on running on url 0.0.0.0 but not on localhost, running it on localhost works fine